# Beta Distribution and Expectation and Variance

Tags: probability, beta-function

Let X ∼ Beta(a, b). Compute E[X] and Var(X).

So confused how to start this question.

Any hint would be helpful.

Comment: Do you know what is the probability density function (pdf) of a Beta distribution?

Comment: $f(x)=(x−a)^(p−1)(b−x)^(q−1)/B(p,q)(b−a)^(p+q−1)    $ when $a≤x≤b;p,q>0$

Comment: Uhm, no.  Not quite.  That's a shifted and scaled beta distribution.  You just asked for that where $a=0, b=1, p=\alpha, q=\beta$. @DeeChantelle

Comment: Wikipedia on 'beta distribution' has the PDF and also the answer to your question. As for the demonstration, perhaps start with various positive integers $a$ and $b = 1.$ Then move on to more difficult cases. If you do not know the definition and properties of the $\Gamma$-function, you'll need to look at that; for integer $a$ and $b$ you can use factorials instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The support of a Beta distribution is always the interval of $(0;1)$.  (Unless shifted or scaled; which you did not asked for.)

The pdf is $X\sim\mathcal{Beta}(\alpha, \beta) \iff f_X(x) = \begin{cases}(x^{\alpha-1} (1-x)^{\beta-1})/(\mathcal B(\alpha, \beta)) & :  0<x<1 \\ 
0 & : \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$

Where $\mathcal B(\cdot ,\cdot )$ is the Beta function: $\mathcal B(\alpha, \beta) = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)} = \int_0^1 u^{\alpha-1} (1-u)^{\beta-1}\operatorname d u$

Where $\Gamma(\cdot)$ is the Gamma function, the extension of the factorial function to the Reals. ...

Use this to compute $\mathsf E(X) = \int_0^1 x\,f_X(x)\operatorname d x$ and then $\mathsf {Var}(X) = \int_0^1 x^2\, f_X(x)\operatorname d x - E(X)^2$.

Comment: Then does it become for the expectation = alpha/ alpha + beta

Comment: And the variance = alpha * beta / (alpha + beta) ^ 2 (alpha + beta + 1) ?

Comment: Yes.  @DeeChantelle Your integration should result in:  $\mathsf E(X)=\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta} \\ \mathsf{Var}(X) = \frac{\alpha\beta}{(\alpha+\beta)^2(\alpha+\beta+1)}$